# function not being called, do I need a window.load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the css stylings of an item when it's clicked.

ryan.js

```
function ryanClicked(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "blue";
    alert("Asdsa");
}
```

product.html

```
<head>
    <script src="ryan.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="sizeButton1"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(sizeButton1)"> S </div>
    <div id ="sizeButton2"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(sizeButton2)"> M </div>
    <div id ="sizeButton3"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(sizeButton3)"> L </div>
```

I assume I need a onReady or onLoad somewhere? I haven't done js in a while.
My page has Jquery included so I can use jquery for the ready event. I'm not sure if that would be better to do or not.

Comment: is it not working? is it giving a console error?

Comment: `ryanClicked('sizeButton1')` note the quotes

Comment: yeah I guess it's not getting the elementById correctly. is there something wrong with the syntax I used to pass the "id" to the function. I thought everything was hashmapped so it didnt matter  I get a: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: ah thank you rory ^^ that worked

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you don't need pass `id` to your function, instead you can pass `this` (refers to element that was clicked),

```js
function ryanClicked(el) {
  el.style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div id="sizeButton1"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(this)">S</div>
<div id="sizeButton2"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(this)">M</div>
<div id="sizeButton3"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(this)">L</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you might prefer:

```
<div id ="sizeButton1" class="sizeButton"> S </div>
<div id ="sizeButton2" class="sizeButton"> M </div>
<div id ="sizeButton3" class="sizeButton"> L </div>
```

and:

```
$(".sizeButton").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("color", "blue")
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/38ybvty8/

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired result without passing id and onclick attribute in your element tag.

```js
$(".sizeButton").click(function(){
   $(this).css({'color':'blue'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="sizeButton1" class="sizeButton" >S </div>
<div id ="sizeButton2" class="sizeButton" >M</div>
<div id ="sizeButton3" class="sizeButton" >L</div>
```